# How to get the respondsToSelector method's return type when it returns primitive type value

Tags: objective-c, ios, selector

I know that I can get the respondsToSelector method's return type with object_getClassName when it returns an object.But it doesn't work when it returns a primitive type like NSInteger.
My app crashed when I init a NSString with a wrong SEL which returns a NSInteger.T_T
What only I can do now is make methods return a NSNumber value when I need them return primitive type. Must I do this? Is there some simple way to get the return type of a SEL when it returns primitive type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem with using `NSNumber`? If you know what the "type" of number is (i.e., integer, float), you can call `-[NSNumber integerValue]` or `-[NSNumber floatValue]` to get the primitive you need.

If you don't happen to know what primitive type will be coming back, you can use the `objCType` property of an `NSNumber` instance to get the C-style string containing the `@encode()` directives. These indicate how Objective-C data is encoded. See [Type Encoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) for more information.

Based on the type encoding C string you get back, you can respond according to whatever primitive type is actually stored inside your `NSNumber` instance and use the aforementioned methods to retrieve the right value.

Comment: Would it lead to high memory usage when I use a large number of NSNumber?

Comment: It shouldn't. You should profile your code if you're concerned, but don't make assumptions beforehand about memory usage, etc. :)

Comment: It does help me a lot,Thank U~~~